# Add online folders to website

Tags: php, html, web

I'm hoping add folders to my website, that users can access with the same flexibility as Windows Explorer / Dropbox etc (ideally anyway). 
I'm on a hosted Unix platform at the moment so can edit htaccess for browse ability & security but that has it's limitations in terms of ease of usability.
Has anyone recommendations as to a direction I should go in in terms of scripting or even third party hosted/cloud solutions? I may need portability to Windows (IIS) platform at some stage but its not a key consideration. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called webdav. Works with apache and iis. There is no caching and windows support isn't that great but it works. If i remember correctly, there is no local caching.

Comment: Yep, webdav would make aloot of sense but I'm on a hosted platform so my options are very limited. I understand this question probably is very broad! Thanks

Comment: You can always get a cheap vps where you are root. Webdav is a simple apache module.